# How to assign a varible to a function, if the function has already been called

Tags: python-3.x

Theres a text file with username, password, and then credit amount. Im trying to take the credit amount from sign in where it is first called then take it to the play() function where I can use it.
To get a variable of login_info from sign_in(), id have to recall the function at the bottom with login_info = sign_in() then use it in play(). But the sign in function has already been called by the from_menu() function. So assigning a variable to it would just call it again.

Any ideas would be much appreciated

```
    print('Welcome to the blackjack table, \nif you have an account please sign in, if you are new please register\n1. Sign in.\n2.Register')
    x = True
    while x:
        menu_choice = input('Choice: ')
        if menu_choice == '1':
            from_menu(menu_choice)
        elif menu_choice == '2':
            from_menu(menu_choice)
        else:
            print('only 1 or 2')



def from_menu(menu_choice):
    if menu_choice == '1':
        sign_in()
    else:
        register()
    


def sign_in():
    x = True
    while x:
        username = input('please input youur username: ')
        password = input('please enter your password: ')
        for line in open('blackjack.txt', 'r').readlines():
            login_info = line.split('-')
            if username == login_info[0] and password == login_info[1]:
                print('Welcome back,' + username)
                print('You have', login_info[3], 'credits in your account!')
                play_choice_user(login_info)
                x = False
def play_choice_user(user_login_info):
    user_credits = int(user_login_info[3])
    print('would you like to play a game of blackjack?')
    x = True
    while x:
        play_choice = input( '1. yes. 2 no:     ')
        if play_choice == '1':
            x = False
            play(user_credits, card_value)
        elif play_choice == '2':
            x = False
            menu()
        else:
            print('only enter 1 or 2')


def play(user_credits, card_value, card_number, card_suit):
    x = True
    while x:
        user_hand_value = 0
        player_bet = input('please enter a starting bet')
        player_bet_integer = int(player_bet)
        new_user_credits = user_credits - player_bet_integer
        print('you have been given a card ', card_number, card_suit)
        user_hand_value = card_value

user_menu_choice = menu()
```

Comment: Apologies, edited that, it was from when I was messing aroung trying to find a different way of doing it, seeing if calling the function by a variable instead of within the other function, didnt harm the code so I forgot about it

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a variable from inside a function you have to `return` it:

```py
def my_sum(a, b):
   c = a+b
   return c

result = my_sum(2,3)
# result = 5
```

You never `return` a value from `sign_in()`, you just `print()` the information. If you `return` the `login_info` you can use it later:

```py
def sign_in():
   ...
   return login_info

logged_in_user = sign_in()
# now logged_in_user is the login_info returned by sign_in
```

Note that `return` ends the processing of a function, so only use it when you're done with that function:

```py
def my_sum(a,b):
   c = a+b
   return c
   print(c) # This line never gets called

c = my_sum(2,3)
```

So, to store the `login_info` you need to `return` it from `sign_in` and store it in a variable for later use.

Comment: Thaks for the reply, I get that. But the problem is logged_in_user = sign_in() calls the sign_in function again, after its already been called by the from_menu function. Ive tried returning the login_info from sign in, but i cant seem to do it without calling the function again

Comment: Store the value returned by `sign_in` the first time you call it, then you don't need to call it again. At the moment you don't `return` anything from any of your functions.